# Crystal Report Error. Failed to open the connection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, crystal-reports, web-deployment-project

I have issue in Crystal Report. I have MySQL database on one server and asp.net C# website on other server. My website shows some reports well but other reports shows following error.
All Crystal Reports work well on localhost.

**Error:**
[Failed to open the connection. Failed to open the connection. ADP_ReportSR1 253736_80084_{B18FB39E-5489-4D73-ACAE-50ACE7A17E83}.rpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EocqI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check datasource referenced in the report.

Look at [Solution: Failed to Open the Connection](https://www.thereportviewer.com/documents/report-viewer-documentation/known-issues-and-solutions/solution-failed-open-connection)

> The computer has to be configured to connect to the datasource
>   referenced in the report.
>
> Setup the system the same way as the computer used to design the
>   reports. Install the same database drivers [...]. Give them the same
>   name.

Look also at [Crystal: Failed to open Connection](https://forums.asp.net/t/997655.aspx?Crystal%20Failed%20to%20open%20Connection) and [Error: Failed To Open The Connection](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/954432).

Comment: Thanks for helping. I want to know where i have to install driver, on PHP database server or asp.net website server. I have also searched for how to install driver in cPanel but i did'nt found any solution. Can you help me in installing driver?

Comment: I would say on web server. The web server running the reports has to connect to db server. Look at Crystal reposrt documentation or follow links above.

Comment: I have already seen these links but i did'nt found, how to install drivers on online server. As i did'nt found any option in my cPanel.